# how to define a "middleman" class's init to successfully passthrough args from the grandchild to the parent in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a semi-abstract `Parent` and `Middle` classes and some `Grandchild` fully implemented ones that inherit from each other, but while the `Parent` and `Grandchild` need some `__init__` args, the middle one is just for shared implemented code:

```py
class Parent:
  def __init__(self, some_arg):
    ...

class Middle(Parent, ABC):
  def do_something_any_middle_can_do():
    ...

class Grandchild(Middle):
  def __init__(self, some_arg):
    super().__init__(some_arg)
    ...
```

As you can see, the `super().__init__(some_arg)` in the `Grandchild` would call the default `__init__` in the `Middle`, and not send `some_arg` to the `Parent`.

So far, I have thought to use `**kwargs`, but that requires the authors of any new `Grandchild` to explicitly name the args in `super().__init__(some_arg=some_arg)` and if they don't unexpected things might happen without a good error message:

```py
class Parent:
  def __init__(self, some_arg):
    ...

class Middle(Parent, ABC):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(kwargs)
    ...

  def do_something_any_middle_can_do():
    ...

class Grandchild(Middle):
  def __init__(self, some_arg):
    super().__init__(some_arg=some_arg)
    ...
```

Comment: `Middle` doesn't define `__init__`, so `super().__init__` calls `Parent.__init__` directly from `Grandchild.__init__`. There is no "default" `__init__` method for any class, only *inherited* `__init__` methods.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, the `super().__init__(some_arg)` in the `Grandchild` would call the default `__init__` in the `Middle`, and not send `some_arg` to the `Parent`.

That's not correct. There is no "default" `__init__` method in `Middle.`

`super().__init__` refers to the `__init__` attribute of the next class in `self`'s method resolution order that has a defined `__init__` method. Since `Middle.__init__` is not defined, that means `Parent.__init__` is called immediately.

---

The advice given in [Python's `super` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) is to use keyword arguments to avoid conflict between which classes define which positional parameters. (It's the responsibility of the class designer to know which keyword arguments each ancestor expects, and to resolve any conflicts between ancestors that use the same name for different purposes.)

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, *, some_arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ...


class Middle(Parent, ABC):
    def do_something_any_middle_can_do(self):
        ...

class Grandchild(Middle):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ...

g = Grandchild(some_arg=3)
```

`Grandchild.__init__` doesn't need to "advertise" `some_arg`; it accepts it as an arbitrary keyword argument and passes it up the chain (via `super().__init__`). Eventually, some class (`Parent`, in this case) has a defined parameter to accept it; otherwise, the argument will be passed to `object.__init__` where an exception will be raised.

Comment: Thank you for disabusing me of my pythonic misconception of default `__init__`s. If you add doc links to that pythonic behavior, I will mark this answer as accepted